# Pre-audit system with Postgres?

Tags: php, postgresql, web-applications

How to implement pre-audit system for a web-app? I mean when the data changes made by regular users are saved for review and only after that they can be applied (or rejected) to main tables.
How to organize and keep in sync relations between data table and preliminary table, when the table name is changed for example, or worse, table structure?
How to validate submitted data for constraints?
Is there something similar that I can use, or read about?

Comment: Not sure if this is an appropriate forum for asking for such general advice. Maybe try and implement and ask more specific questions?

Comment: @scott, I don't want to go the wrong way from the start